# Availablity of APIs for sport, event and live concert's schedules and tickets?

Tags: xml, json, web-services, api, rest

Are there any APIs related to sports and live concerts (schedules and buying tickets) in US region are available to implement a website like below.

"http://www.tickpick.com/"

"https://www.fanxchange.com/"

"https://seatgeek.com/"